# Checking the name of a VB.NET treeview node regardless of if it exists

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview

I am trying to add nodes to a treeview based on what i have stored in a database on a form load. I am working with exactly 2 levels of node; one root and one level of child. When I cycle through what is currently stored in the treeview, the program refuses to return a NULL response so that conditionals can be met.

My Code

```
Sub PopulateTree()

    Dim RNum As Integer = RecNum()
    Dim TreeData() As Tree = GetTreeValues(RNum)
    Dim I = 0
    Dim allnodes As TreeNodeCollection = treHierarchy.Nodes

    For I = 0 To RNum - 1
        'find the notation of reading the properties of a node
        MsgBox(treHierarchy.Nodes(I).Name.ToString)
        MsgBox(TreeData(I).Parent)

        'If the node is equal to the parent of THAT record, then append the child
        If treHierarchy.Nodes(I).Name = TreeData(I).Parent Then
            treHierarchy.SelectedNode = treHierarchy.Nodes(I)
            treHierarchy.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(TreeData(I).Child)

            'If the node is equal to A parent BUT NOT the parent of THAT record, then skip.
            'When the code hits the end, create the new parent
        ElseIf treHierarchy.Nodes(I).Text <> TreeData(I).Parent Then
            For Each TreeNode In allnodes
                If TreeNode <> TreeData(I).Parent Then
                    treHierarchy.Nodes.Add(TreeData(I).Parent)
                    treHierarchy.SelectedNode = treHierarchy.Nodes(I)
                    treHierarchy.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(TreeData(I).Child)
                Else
                    treHierarchy.SelectedNode = treHierarchy.Nodes(I)
                    treHierarchy.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(TreeData(I).Child)
                End If
            Next
            'If the node is a child, then skip
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I've tried to use comments to explain (partially to myself), what I want to do with each part of the IF statement

Comment: Which conditionals are not working as expected, and what values are being returned instead of what you expect?

Comment: I'm struggling to get the treHierarchy.Nodes(I).Name part to read the name of a selected node name, or reply NULL or no answer if there isnt any nodes currently in the treeview

Comment: Struggling how?  if treHeirarchy.Nodes(i) doesn't exist, then you'll receive an Object Ref error, since you can't access the .Name property of something that doesn't exist.  Check to make sure it exists before trying to do things on it.